# Why is FileVersionInfo.FileMinorPart (an int) documented in MSDN to possibly be null?

Tags: c#, msdn

In MSDN [Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.productminorpart.aspx) it says that, for example, `ProductMinorPart` returns an int or `null` if the value is undefined. However it's not a `Nullable<int>` - how can it return null?
I checked with ILDasm, and the definition is a normal int, no Nullable...

Am I missing something?

Comment: The bled in by accident, ProductVersion can be null.

Comment: @HansPassant well, that one is a string :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't appear to be missing something. I'd say the documentation is inaccurate.

It appears that the property returns 0 if the minor part is missing, or if the entire version is missing all together.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, and it returned 0. I didn't know that 0 for int for null :-)

Comment: The MSDN articles include a feedback link for problems like this. I threw a quick note in there for that property: *This property (and others in this class besides) is documented to return null "if the file did not contain version information". Since this property is not nullable, this isn't possible - the properties instead return 0 in this case.*

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I was headed in the same direction, but weirdly I don't see the "Community Content" section for the .NET 4.5 version of the documentation.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta way to go, I will remember next time :-)

Comment: @vcsjones: it's hidden. Look for *Did you find this helpful?*, answer "no", and a feedback form magically appears. Do they listen? Dunno, but worth a try.